# How to setup Eclipse PDT on a bare Windows box?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have installed Eclipse PDT All-In-One and nothing works (I can edit PHP source but cannot execute any PHP Scripts).

Do I also need to install my own PHP interpreter? Do I need XAMPP? WAMP? Cygwin? XDebug? Zend?

I'm looking for the smallest amount of stuff that I need to install to get a working PHP IDE, starting with an empty install of Windows Vista.

I have tried installing XAMPP and setting PHP Executable, but that doesn't work.

Still getting "No PHP executables defined".

Comment: how are you trying to execute the PHP? localhost in a browser? with XAMPP I think they have a specific URL for execution.

Comment: I was trying "Run As... PHP Script"

Answer (score 1):

- Eclipse PDT all in one
- `PHP`
- <del>a web server (XAMPP for instance)</del> (as mentioned by [Phill Pafford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93966/phill-pafford) in the comments: " XAMPP comes with PHP so no need to install another instance of it")
- [a debugger](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/FAQ#Does_PDT_include_a_debugger.3F_Where_can_i_find_one.3F) (XDebug or Zend)

BUT: once PDT is installed, to avoid the error message:

[alt text http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_no-PHP-executables-defined_540x148_en_64c.png](http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_no-PHP-executables-defined_540x148_en_64c.png)

you need to one (PHP executable) through the preferences:

[alt text http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_preferences_php-executables_en_530x378_64c.png](http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_preferences_php-executables_en_530x378_64c.png)

, like `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.8\php.exe` sous Wamp.

[alt text http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_new-php-executable_en_337x200_128c.png](http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_new-php-executable_en_337x200_128c.png)

Check also the coherence with the debug settings:

[alt text http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_preferences_php-debug_en_500x372_128c.png](http://www.phpfacile.com/images/eclipse_pdt/eclipse-pdt_preferences_php-debug_en_500x372_128c.png)

Comment: I did all the above, but with XAMPP 1.7.3 not WAMP. Xdebug has 8 versions to choose from, so I decided to skip that trial-and-error nightmare. It looks like http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/all-in-one/zend-eclipse-php-galileo-SR1-win32-x86.zip already comes with Zend Debugger, so I chose that. But still this doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex: that leaves us with your launching configuration. If your settings are correctly set in the PHP proferences, you shouldn't see a "No PHP executables defined" unless, somehow when launching your debug session, you are not using those settings.

Comment: XAMPP comes with PHP so no need to install another instance of it

Comment: Also Aptana (Which is Eclipse based) is another free IDE for PHP (And other) development

Comment: I installed Aptana, and didn't really notice any difference.